# jQuery Reaction Test Delay Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

I was just having a couple of problems with a reaction test I was making:

- Well, firstly I would like to have a random pause (for 2-5 seconds) after the player clicks on a div.
- And secondly, I want to have the divs appear a total of 5 times, so the player gets 5 attempts.

For the first problem, I tried to use the setTimeout function. And I attempted to resolve the second issue by using a 'for' loop to restrict the number of times the div would appear.

```
For example:

    for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
        $div.css({
            left: Math.floor(Math.random() * widthMax),
            top: Math.floor(Math.random() * heightMax)
        });
    }
```

However, I could not resolve either of these problems.

You can try it out here:
http://jsfiddle.net/tghca/7/

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: the delay if for what? after the click to relocate the div? or to enable next click

Comment: Can you please add a specific list of events with the properties (visibility) of the div? I currently don't exactly understand when the div appears and disappears.

Comment: like in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/un9b9/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Sorry for not making it 100% clear. I don't want the div to change position immediately after it is clicked - I want a pause after it is clicked.

Comment: @kpsuperplane Sorry, the div does not disappear and reappear - the location just changes to a random position.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yes! Thank you so much - that's what I was looking for. Do you think we could make it so that the div 'disappears' immediately, however 'reappears' after 2-5 seconds?

Comment: @user2840892 yes we could... see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
$('div').hide();

$('.start').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.hint').hide();
    $('div').show();
    makeDiv();
});

var counter = 0;

function testClick() {
    var docHeight = $(document).height(),
        docWidth = $(document).width(),
        $div = $('#test'),
        divWidth = $div.width(),
        divHeight = $div.height(),
        heightMax = docHeight - divHeight,
        widthMax = docWidth - divWidth;

    $div.hide();
    setTimeout(function () {
        $div.css({
            left: Math.floor(Math.random() * widthMax),
            top: Math.floor(Math.random() * heightMax)
        }).show();
        counter++;
        if (counter < 5) {
            makeDiv();
        }
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000) + 2000)
}

function makeDiv() {
    $('#test').one('click', testClick);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/un9b9/)